# How me for Incorrect syntax near 'stock'

Tags: asp.net

```
public string update()
        {
           try
            {
                myConnection.ConnectionString = GlobalVariabel.connString;
                myConnection.Open();
                string query = "update phoneproduct set ";
                query += "model = @model,";
                query += "price = @price ";
                query += "stock = @stock ";
                query += "employeeid = @employeeid";
                query += "where pin = @pin";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", pin);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", employeeid);
                int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    flag = "OK";
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = "FAIL";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                flag = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                    myConnection = null;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your code? While it’s nearly formatted in your screenshot,it’s really hard to read in the question itself. Also, what error are you getting, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tip: when a command string you built gives errors, inspect the final string. Is it what you expected?

Comment: Good that you are using parameters but [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 1):

```
            string query = "update phoneproduct set ";
            query += "model = @model,";
            query += "price = @price ";
            query += "stock = @stock ";
            query += "employeeid = @employeeid";
            query += "where pin = @pin";
```

the above will build the query

```
UPDATE phoneproduct
SET model = @model,
price = @price
stock = @stock
employeeid = @employeeid
WHERE pin = @pin
```

The issue is that you are missing a comma after `@price` and `@stock`